# How do i POST selected option using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Am using Ajax in Laravel to store data, Below is the form i use to store data, it has input and also selected option

```
  <form class="forms" method="get" action="">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
          
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Estate Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control Estate_name" name="Estate_name" id="exampleInputUsername2" placeholder="Enter Estate Name" >
                        </div>
          
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Landlord</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control Landlord" name="Landlord" id="exampleInputEmail2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Landlord" >
                        </div>
                      </div>
          
                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">District</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <select class="js-example-basic-single w-200 District_id" name="District_id">
                            @foreach ($District as $districts)
                            <option value="{{$districts -> id}}">{{$districts -> DISTRICT}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                          </select>
                        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Below is the script to insert data but i don't know how to best write the code that stores selected option. i need help on that!, the select option is supposed to insert "District_id" into the DB.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
      
          $(document).on('click', '.add_estate', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //console.log("Hello")
            var data = {
              'Estate_name': $('.Estate_name').val(),
              'Landlord': $('.Landlord').val(),
              'District_id': $('.District_id').val(),//this is where i fail to insert
            }
            //console.log(data);
            //Call Ajax Methoad
            $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
            });
    
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:"/register/estate",
              data: data,
              dataType: "json",
              sucess: function (response) {
                  console.log(response); 
              }
            });
    
          });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: because `$('District_id')` is looking for `<District_id>` element

Comment: @epascarello and how do i write it well?

Comment: Well how did you write the other ones that work? :) You literally did it two times right above it.

Comment: See how input differs from the select

Comment: You are looking for an ELEMENT TAG, not a CLASSNAME. You are literally missing a `.` in the selector.

Comment: @epascarello thanks that was a typing error in the question but the select still does not insert the option

Comment: Well I just ran your code and it works perfectly fine. It reads the value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237836/discussion-between-matovu-joel-clinton-and-epascarello).

Comment: @epascarello My form Data at raw shows this -> ( **District_id: ""**). meaning its not getting anything from the option, any hint?

Comment: Well my guess is there is no value in your option

Comment: @epascarello tell me look into that and revert shortly

Comment: @epascarello well have tested with just this **(value="1")** and it work, thanks anyway. let me figure it out myself now

Answer (score 0):

Second, you can trigger the event of the form using the submit event
Then you can serialize the info so your ajax request should look like this

```
$(".forms").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action'); //you can paste your URL directly if you want /register/estate
    
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); 
           }
         });

    
});
```

Comment: can you complete it i see?